# google apps script - "Only the owner of a script can publish the script as an add-on." who is the owner, if not me?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just created a script with google app-script. Now I try to publish it as a sheets add-on. However, I get above mentioned error-code: "Only the owner of a script can publish the script as an add-on."

How can I find out who google thinks is the owner of this script/project? I am certain that I made it, and did not use any other accounts to modify it ever. "project properties" does not tell me anything.

Are there any circumstances in which this might occur that are not immediately obvious? I made the script into a project I made a year ago or so. Same user account though.

The *sheet* I created it from however, is owned by another account, I just checked. Does that set the owner of the script?

Comment: Is this a **bound** script?

Comment: Open your G Suite Developer Hub at [https://script.google.com/home](https://script.google.com/home)  From the list of "My Projects" click on the project.  On the right there will be information about who the owner is and what your role is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the script is bound to a spreadsheet that is owned by another account. If that's the case, then the script is also owned by that account, and your account's role is most probably `Editor`.

As you can see [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts): "All container-bound scripts use the same owner, viewer, and editor access list defined for the container file. **The container owner takes ownership of a new script project regardless of who created it**".

You will notice that your project doesn't show up in `My Projects`, but only in `All Projects`. Also, as indicated by another user, you can check who the project owner is and what your role is if you click on `Project details` on the right in your dashboard.

Kind regards.